# Does a Function run Asynchronously if I don't set look for the result?

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, vb6

I have a function that makes a web call in a VB6 program.

```
Function httpget(sURL) As String
    Dim obj As Object
    Set obj = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    obj.Open "GET", sURL, False
    obj.send
    httpget = obj.responseText
End Function
```

If I call it like:

```
httpget "site.com"
```

vs.

```
result=httpget ("site.com")
```

it runs twice as fast (in first option, not "capturing" function's return value)
 (over 20 tests, 100% consistent) if I don't look for the return value.

Is this running asynchronously?
(That's what I'm *trying* to do)

Comment: The False you're sending to the obj.Open says you don't want async (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536648(v=vs.85).aspx).  The only reason I can see that performance would differ is that you're not copying the result to a local string in the caller.  How big is the response?

Comment: Seriously? The `varAsync` argument defaults to `True` just as documented.  This should be covered in both your MSDN CDs and the MSDN web site.

Comment: @OldBoyCoder, it's .03125 seconds  vs. .0156 seconds, to roughly DOUBLE. Since the http call is done synchronously, I"m really surprised at the increase in time from assigning a value to a string. (You'd think a call to a server would be orders of magnitude greater)